# Вызвать метод из промиса

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vuejs 2. В компоненте есть метод `updatePerson()`, который использует [async axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#example). И внутри мне нужно вызвать другой метод `setPersonData()`. Как можно это сделать?

```
methods: {
    setPersonData(data) {
        this.clearAll();
        this.setPerson(data);
    },
    updatePerson(person) {
        this.$awn.confirm('Update?', async function () {
            let response = await axios.patch('/people/' + person.id, person);
            this.setPersonData(response); //Не работает, т.к. this относится к промису
        });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно объявить переменную ссылающуюся на данный объект

```
methods: {
    setPersonData(data) {
        this.clearAll();
        this.setPerson(data);
    },
    updatePerson(person) {
        var that = this; // запоминаем объект
        this.$awn.confirm('Update?', async function () {
            let response = await axios.patch('/people/' + person.id, person);
            that.setPersonData(response); // ссылаемся на объект Vue
        });
    },
}
```

как правильно в комментах написали - можно воспользоваться стрелочными функциями

```
    updatePerson(person) {
        this.$awn.confirm('Update?', async () => {
            let response = await axios.patch('/people/' + person.id, person);
            this.setPersonData(response); // ссылаемся на объект Vue
        });
    },
```

Comment: а `() => {}`? :-(

Comment: За `var that = this;` в наше время я бы по рукам линейкой бил ))) Есть же стрелочные функции.

Comment: эт, да, но если нет babel, то вполне норм... а хотя какого черта тут же async/await))

Comment: @DemoGosha кстати реально непонятно зачем тут async/await, модно походу) `axios.patch('/people/' + person.id, person).then(this.setPersonData);` будет абсолютно аналогичен ;)